# drupal view, how to group by content type

Tags: drupal, statistics, content-type, drupal-views

I want to make a view that shows the most visited article from each content type, so I want to group by content type, and sort by node statistics views, desc
Is there any way to do this in one view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create each view by you want to output,then in the template file using `views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default')`. that you can get group by content type